# php function with with multiple queries - inner join duplicating results?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have been tackling trying to incorporate and implement a shopping cart system.

**How do I make it display 1 add to cart button with each shop product listing with the correct price showing?**

I have a function in my functions file. And the function has 2 queries in it.

first table called: `products`

```
    $results = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `products` INNER JOIN `shop` ON `products`.`id` = `shop`.`id`;");
    $paypalContent = "";
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
        {
```

second table called: `shop`

```
    $results = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shop ");
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
    {
```

I use

```
unset($results);
unset($row);
```

to unset the results so that the second query can be queried.

So basically my results is resulting in it repeating the add to cart buttons for all rows in the products table. I will show a picture.

[image]

So table info: the shop table has all info in it, 18 rows with pictures and links and descriptions etc etc.

Structure:

```
 table 1 - products: id, name, image, price, status 
 table 2 - shop: id,title, name, standardprice, commercialprice, image, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, description, descr, more, moredetails, url, paypalstandard, paypalcommercial
```

I will be removing the paypalstandard and paypalcommercial once i got this working. also the standardprice and commercial price is for other pages.

Second table is basically for the products so it creates the buttons for the paypal end in a form.

So I do have a row for standard and commercial in each table, products and shop.
So I need it to display the correct add to cart button for each shop listing -
 which is 1 button for each listing. It is needing to be linked to the product so it creates the correct button and price for each shop product.

EDIT: So I need it to show 1 button per shop item. so as you see in the picture above it shows 4 buttons. I need it to show just 1 for each with the correct price reflected in each product.

FURTHER EDIT: My 2 tables both have `id` and both are primary keys. I have tried many different queries with left and right join to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: sorry but I can't understand what you want to ask from this long story

Comment: I explain what my issue is in my above post just under the second query code snippet and also in the title. the second query is resulting in duplicated buttons. I need it to only display the correct button for each shop product. I will edit my question to further explain how i want it.

Comment: I have now updated my question to fully explain what i need?

Comment: Can we have database structure ?

Comment: ok yes sure, give me some minutes to write it and format it correctly :)

Comment: @JayminNoob - updated my post with the table structure for you :)

Answer (score -3):

Well first to start i'd recommend you to use JS making the temporary cart for front end. After you build up a data and send int as json or whatever and just update using the needed items, dont reserve or inner because its not needed. Wait the xhr or whatever your php post the data and just update with the data dont use inner because its not needed at all.

Comment: this is not even an answer to my issue and question :(

Comment: Well i didn't get much your point if you're trying to save the user cart as a storage db or if you want to update directly. You know that usually js saves it on cookies and you retrieve from the user local information and send it not save on a database but well explain urself better and i'll try to help